# Error (Meteor.bindEnvironment) when writing to MongoDB - Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I've created a timer that writes to MongoDb every 500ms. I'm doing this so that every client that is subscribed sees the same Timer. However when I run it I get the error:

*Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. Try wrapping callbacks that you pass to non-Meteor libraries with Meteor.bindEnvironment.*

I've been reading about Meteor.bindEnviroment but don't understand how to apply it with my code. Any thoughts?

```
Meteor.methods({
  updateTime: function() {

    var id = PlayersList.find().fetch()[0]._id;
    var running = false;
    var seconds = 20000; // (1 sec = 1000)
    var then; // Timer start time

    // ------------------------------------
    // Evaluate and route
    // ------------------------------------

    function router(id) {
      if (!running) {
        run(id);
      }
    };

    // ------------------------------------
    // Run the timer
    // ------------------------------------

    function run(id) {
      running = true;
      then = Date.now() + seconds;
      var interval = setInterval(function(){
        var time = parseTime(then-Date.now());
        if (time[0] > 0) {
          var time = time[0] + '.' + time[1];
          PlayersList.update({ _id: id }, { $set:{time : time }});
          // console.log(time);
        } else {
          console.log('0.00');
          running = false;
          clearInterval(interval);
          router();
        }
      }, 500);
    };

    // ------------------------------------
    // Parse time in MS for output
    // ------------------------------------

    function parseTime(elapsed) {
      // Array of time multiples [sec, decimal]
      var d = [1000,10];
      var time = [];
      var i = 0;
        while (i < d.length) {
          var t = Math.floor(elapsed/d[i]);
          // Remove parsed time for next iteration
          elapsed -= t*d[i];
          t = (i > 0 && t < 10) ? '0' + t : t;
          time.push(t);
          i++;
        } 
      return time;
    };

    router(id);
  }
});
```

Comment: Don't use `setInterval`, use `Meteor.setInterval`

Comment: Thanks! Works @corvid